# Pulumi and AKS : Public IP not linked to AKS load-balancer

Tags: azure, pulumi, pulumi-azure

trying, using pulumi, to setup and AKS cluster with a public ip as load-balancer and a domain name.
I tried several options using the following project : https://github.com/hostettler/pulumi-az-test

I end up with a working AKS cluster (great!) ,  that has a load-balancer (amazing!), on a public ip (fantastic!),  but with an fqdn that is not linked to the public ip of the load-balancer (huh!).

I tried to

1. extract the public ip to force the domain but I did not manage to do it. I get the resource id of the public id created but I cannot cast it
   as a public ip object to set the domain. Meaning how to load a public ip object from a public ip resource-id.
   "/subscriptions/XXXXXX-XXX-XX-XXXx-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/MC_XXXXX_XXXXX_aksCluster5632b82_eastus/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXX"
2. tries to add a public ip to the cluster but that ip, while having a good fqdn is not used by the load-balancer

Any idea on how to address? Solving either would be ok with me.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you share the code you used to provision the cluster?

Comment: @jaxxstorm : you do not have access to the link in the message? https://github.com/hostettler/pulumi-az-test it should be public. Let me double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem (or rather a work around). The problem stems from the helm chart I was using. The bitnami nginx chart seemed to ignored the `controller.service.loadBalanceIP`. Therefore, I replaced it by the ingress-nginx.

Thus, replacing

```
chart: "nginx",
version: "13.2.10",
fetchOpts: {
    repo: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami",
},
```

by

```
chart: "ingress-nginx",
version: "4.3.0",
fetchOpts: {
    repo: "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx",
},
```

solved the problem. Instead of recreating an external ip address for each deployment, it used the one provided in `controller.service.loadBalanceIP` that is static and with the proper A record.

```
import * as azure from "@pulumi/azure";
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as config from "./config";
import * as azuread from "@pulumi/azuread";

const current = azuread.getClientConfig({});

// Create a Virtual Network for the cluster
const aksVnet = new azure.network.VirtualNetwork("aks-net", {
    resourceGroupName: config.resourceGroup.name,
    addressSpaces: ["10.2.0.0/16"],
});

// Create a Subnet for the cluster
const aksSubnetId = new azure.network.Subnet("aks-net", {
    resourceGroupName: config.resourceGroup.name,
    virtualNetworkName: aksVnet.name,
    addressPrefixes: ["10.2.1.0/24"],
    serviceEndpoints : ["Microsoft.Sql"],
},
{dependsOn: [aksVnet]}
);

// Now allocate an AKS cluster.
export const k8sCluster = new azure.containerservice.KubernetesCluster("aksCluster", {
    resourceGroupName: config.resourceGroup.name,
    location: config.location,
    defaultNodePool: {
        name: "aksagentpool",
        nodeCount: config.nodeCount,
        vmSize: config.nodeSize,
        vnetSubnetId: aksSubnetId.id,
    },
    dnsPrefix: `${pulumi.getStack()}-reg-engine`,

    linuxProfile: {
        adminUsername: "aksuser",
        sshKey: {
            keyData: config.sshPublicKey,
        },
    },
    networkProfile: {
        networkPlugin : "azure",
        loadBalancerProfile: {
            managedOutboundIpCount: 1,
        },
        loadBalancerSku: "standard",
        outboundType: "loadBalancer",
    },
    identity: {
        type: "SystemAssigned",
    },
},
{dependsOn: [aksSubnetId]}
);

const publicIp = new azure.network.PublicIp("app-engine-ip", {
    resourceGroupName: k8sCluster.nodeResourceGroup,
    allocationMethod: "Static",
    domainNameLabel : "app-engine",
    sku : "Standard",
    tags: {
        service: "kubernetes-api-loadbalancer",
    },
},
{dependsOn: [k8sCluster]}
);

// Expose a K8s provider instance using our custom cluster instance.
export const k8sProvider = new k8s.Provider("aksK8s", {
    kubeconfig: k8sCluster.kubeConfigRaw,
});

const clusterSvcsNamespace = new k8s.core.v1.Namespace(
    config.namespace,    
    undefined,
{ provider: k8sProvider });
export const clusterSvcsNamespaceName = clusterSvcsNamespace.metadata.name;

const regEngineIngress = new k8s.helm.v3.Chart(
    "sample-engine-ingress",
    {
        repo: "kubernetes.github.io",
        chart: "ingress-nginx",
        version: "4.3.0",
        fetchOpts: {
            repo: "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx",
        },
        namespace: clusterSvcsNamespace.metadata.name,
        values: {
            controller: {
                replicaCount: 2,
                nodeSelector: {
                    "kubernetes\.io/os": "linux",
                },
                service: {
                    loadBalancerIP: publicIp.ipAddress,
                }
            }
        },
    },
    { provider: k8sProvider },
);

export let cluster = k8sCluster.name;
export let kubeConfig = k8sCluster.kubeConfigRaw;
export let k8sFqdn = k8sCluster.fqdn;
export let externalIp = publicIp.ipAddress;
```